# convert mp4 video to avi video with GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, avi

I have tried with GStreamer pipeline to convert mp4 video to avi video but it is convert without sound

> gst-launch -t -v filesrc location=source.mp4 ! qtdemux ! ffdec_h264 ! video/x-raw-yuv ! avimux ! filesink location=result-yuv.avi

Answer (score 0):

Try this pipeline if you want audio in your avi file:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -t -v filesrc location=source.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! video/x-raw-yuv ! queue ! avimux name=mux ! filesink location=result-yuv.avi demux. ! queue ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! queue ! mux.
```